# get tag with numerical order nokogiri ruby

Tags: html, ruby, tags, nokogiri

I have this html :

```
<div class="blah blah">
   <h4> 1 </h4>
   <h4> 2 </h4>
   <h5> 3 </h4>
</div>
```

How can i get inner text of `h4` tag by it's  numerical order. Ex: when numerical order is 2, I have text `2`

Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect any input, e.g. a single order number? What do you want as output? What if there are other `<h4>` tags after the `<h5>`, what happens to the order then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple css selector:

`page.search('h4:nth-child(2)').first.text`

If you want more flexable solution you could simply take all the childs of the div class that you are interested in:

`page.search('div.blah > h4').find { |node| predicate?(node) } #your condition goes in the block.`

I personally would stick with css selectors because it is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'nokogiri'

html_string = '<div class="blah blah"><h4> 1 </h4><h4> 2 </h4><h5> 3 </h4></div>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_string)

puts doc.css('.blah h4').to_a[1].text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.blah h4:nth-child(2){
color: #666666;
}
```

That will do fine, if you meant targeting with CSS.

What do you need to do?

You can always put an ID on the one that you want to target and then target it by ID.